# Pick elements from list of sets to cover all sets with exactly one element

Tags: python

I am looking for the idiomatic and fast python solution for the following problem.
Input is a list of sets. For example, 3 sets of strings.

```
[
{a, b, c, d, e},
{a, c, e, f, g},
{e, f, a, d, l}
]
```

I would like to find all choices of string combinations so that there is only one element in combination per set.

For example, these are "mappings" that show at what list positions these strings occur:

```
a -> 0, 1, 2
b -> 0
c -> 0, 1
d -> 0, 2
e -> 0, 1, 2
f -> 1, 2
g -> 1
l -> 2
```

So the correct solution is the following list of sets

```
a
b, g, l
b, f
e
c, l
d, g
```

Here are some examples of incorrect solutions:

```
a, b # incorrect because more than one element (2) from set 0 are used
b, l # incorrect because less than one element (0) from set 1 is used
```

I tried naive recurrent solution that adds one element at a time from the row and then checks remaining rows if they met requirements or not. It was extremely slow (probably because I overused list concatenations, copies, etc). I am looking for the solution that will work relatively fast (less than 10 s) for 100 rows of sets where each of them has 50 elements in average.

As noted in the comments this problem may not be solvable in finite time with these constraints. In that case I am still interested in the python solution that will work with weaker constraints (e.g. alphabet size 30, average set size 10, number of sets 50).

Comment: Why isn't `{d}` a valid answer?  Do you need the subset to span ALL of the input sets?

Comment: @TimRoberts It doesn't cover input set 1. So you are right, I need to span all input sets.

Comment: How large is the alphabet? That is, how large is the union of all sets?

Comment: @orip It is unbounded, they are general python strings like `abc`, `foobar`. There is a boundary by the size of expected input `100 * 50 = 5000` though.

Comment: @Curious Sure, but you could map them to integers. How large is the union of all sets?

Comment: With the problem as stated, 10s will not be enough to guarantee a solution in the worst case.  However, I suspect that you will be able to handle most cases (i.e. real-world applications) by adapting the standard algorithms for the problem.  This is a special case of the "set coverage" problem, having the additional restriction of unique coverage.  I don't see specific mention of the canonical algorithms, so I think you still have some research to do.  I hope the term "set coverage problem" is helpful to you.

Comment: How is this solvable in finite time?  There's no alternative besides exhaustive search, and that means checking 50! options, which is 10**62.

Comment: @Prune yes, this is definitely helpful. How you get to conclusion that 10 s is not enough?

Comment: Construct the worst cases.  Note the combinatorial explosion.  You may have to navigate a large proportion of the 2^100 sets of 50 elements each, with processing overhead and backtracking for each combination.  How many of those can your processing cluster handle per second?  My single machine can't do it.  Coverage, yes -- *unique* coverage is a longer computation.

Comment: I would suggest using some recursion algorithm that picks items from each set, using the set difference for each step. Eg, if we get 'a' from set_0 then we can only get second item from set_1-set_0+items_already_taken ==> {'f', 'g', 'a'}, third item can be taken only from: set_2-set_1-set_0 + items_already_taken ==> {'l', 'a', plus item from set_1 if different from 'a'}, etc. This will reduce the search field significantly for larger lists.

Comment: @TimRoberts *"How is this solvable in finite time?"* - 50! is finite.

Comment: Even with an alphabet of 30, doing one test per nanosecond, this would still take 8 quadrillion years.  You need to do the math on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a SAT solver like `z3` for this.

```
import z3

sets = [
    {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"},
    {"a", "c", "e", "f", "g"},
    {"e", "f", "a", "d", "l"}
]

alphabet = set.union(*sets)
zvars = {w: z3.Bool(w) for w in alphabet}

sol = z3.Solver()
for s in sets:
    # Exactly one in each set.
    sol.add(z3.PbEq([(zvars[w], True) for w in s], 1))

# Iterate over all solutions.
while sol.check() == z3.sat:
    model = sol.model()
    print({w for w, v in zvars.items() if bool(model[v])})

    # Prevent same solution being returned.
    trues = [v for v in zvars.values() if bool(model[v])]
    falses = [z3.Not(v) for v in zvars.values() if not bool(model[v])]
    sol.add(z3.Not(z3.And(trues + falses)))
```

Solution:

```
{'e'}
{'g', 'd'}
{'g', 'b', 'l'}
{'b', 'f'}
{'c', 'l'}
{'a'}
```